# Indexing in infinispan with xml configuration

Tags: configuration, infinispan

I have configured indexing using xml configuration to local-cache . I am using infinispan 9.1.2 version.

```
        <indexing index="LOCAL" auto-config="true">
            <indexed-entities>
               <indexed-entity>com.x.Emplyee/indexed-entity>
            </indexed-entities>
        </indexing>
```

but it gives me exception

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Indexing was not enabled on this cache. interface org.hibernate.search.spi.SearchIntegrator not found in registry

cache element is annotated  by @Index and @Field

Strange?

Comment: can you tell the Infinispan version and paste the stack trace? Do you have infinispan-query jar in your classpath/maven dependencies?

Comment: Infinispan 9.1.2 version... also same version for infinispan-query-9.1.2.Final.jar in class path

Comment: I have upgraded to 9.4.21...java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.hibernate.search.spi.SearchIntegrator not found in component registry

2020-12-15 12:08:24,253 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)  at com.tieto.teis.ext.infinispan@9.4.21.Final//org.infinispan.query.impl.ComponentRegistryUtils.getRequiredComponent(ComponentRegistryUtils.java:28)

2020-12-15 12:08:24,253 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)  at com.tieto.teis.ext.infinispan@9.4.21.Final//org.infinispan.query.impl.ComponentRegistryUtils.getSearchIntegrator(ComponentRegistryUtils.java:42)

Comment: java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.hibernate.search.spi.SearchIntegrator not found in component registry

Comment: can you double-check if you are accessing the right cache?

Comment: Yes... I am accessing the right cache.

Comment: @SatishShelake what's the meaning of `com.tieto.teis.ext.infinispan@9.4.21.Final//org.infinispan.query.impl.ComponentRegistryUtils`? Are you running in some kind of container?

Comment: Did you resolve this?

Comment: Not Resolved... I have upgraded to 9.4.20 infinispan... but couldn't find lucene index on filesystem  <indexing index="LOCAL" >
    <property name="default.directory_provider">filesystem</property>
     <property name="lucene_version">LUCENE_CURRENT</property>
    <property name="default.indexmanager">directory-based</property>
    <property name="default.indexBase">${java.io.tmpdir}/CacheIndexes</property>   
   </indexing>